# "No such file or directory" error when downloading with 'youtube-dl'

Tags: 12.04, command-line, video, python, youtube

Every time I try to download YouTube videos using **youtube-dl** it gives me this:

```
ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:<br> 'Filename.mp4.part'
```

How can I fix this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The version of `youtube-dl` in the 12.04 repositories is out of date, update it with the following command:

```
sudo youtube-dl --update
```

It should work after that.

If you don't have root privileges, set an output file as a workaround:

```
youtube-dl -o ~/Videos http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0YiWsAM0O8
```

Comment: this problem still exists even on 2021.06.06 version and this method is a temporary workaround and it works

Answer (score 0):

I was told that youtube-dl no longer works well and the instead you need to download yt-dlp. The command I use to download videos is:

```
yt-dlp --ffmpeg-location /usr/bin <url>
```

Works every time.